# JSF Ajax request - how to stop scrolling top after ajax request

Tags: jsf-2

I've a datatable that is wrapped inside a div.  This div has a fix height with overflow: auto, which will cause vertical scroll bar to show when overflow occurred.  This datatable has a EDIT link on each row, where user can click on to edit data.  This link is a commandlink with ajax.  The ajax is working fine.  The problem that I'm having is that  after the ajax refreshed that datatable, the vertical scroll bar is being repositioned to the top.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem by changing the render attribute of the ajax tag form @form to the datatable id.

thanks